# chmod doesn't work in mounted partition

Tags: linux, chmod

I have this file in my mounted partition

```
/path/to/hardDiskDrive/$ ls -l 
-rw------- 1 arash arash  92827804 Jun 15 17:35 qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run
```

and then try to chmod it but nothing happens **even with sudo**

```
/path/to/hardDiskDrive/$ chmod +x qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run 
/path/to/hardDiskDrive/$ ls -l 
-rw------- 1 arash arash  92827804 Jun 15 17:35 qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run
```

but when i copy it to my Linux home directory everything works fine .. 
What is the resne of this ?!!

```
~/Desktop $ ls -l
-rw-------  1 arash arash  92827804 Jun 15 17:35 qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run
~/Desktop $ chmod +x qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run
~/Desktop $ ls -l
-rwx--x--x  1 arash arash  92827804 Jun 15 17:35 qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86
```

What is the reason of this?!! and How can i run this file from original place in Hard Drive?
thanks

Comment: chances are it is a shell script. In that case you can run it using `sh qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run` even without execute permission. As to why the chmod doesn't work: no idea. Could be mounted read-only but then I'd expect an error message.

Comment: i can make dir easily and its not read-only, also _root_ with _su_ couldn't change it to x,  i tried sh and the out put is: '$ sh ./qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run
./qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run: 1: ./qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run: cannot create �*B@��@8: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
./qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run: 1: ./qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run: ELF: not found
./qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.0.2.run: 2: ./qt-creator-opensource-linu...: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
'

Comment: ok so it's not a shell script ;-)

Comment: is this a networked drive? usb? what is the file system type? Perhaps SE-Linux? Can you `ls -Z` to show perhaps additional SELinux security context. Either way it's weird you get no error message. Perhaps the file is in use?

Comment: You can only `chmod` on unix-style file systems like `ext4`. `chmod` is not supported on fat32 or ntfs, because these use different types of permissions.

Comment: yes your right, its NTFS file system. thank u so much! :-D